# What's the AES password length equivalent to 2048bit PGP key?

Tags: passwords, aes, pgp, password-cracking

Simply put : Let's say i have a document and i want to encrypt it. I have my password and i have my 2048 bit PGP key. How long should that password be to be as strong(hard to crack) as PGP is ?

Comment: AES does not have a password length, AES has a key length. While the key might be derived from the password the key should be more or less random while the password should usually be memorable. So length of password and key cannot really be compared but it is probably easier to guess the password than the derived key.

Comment: [This post](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9361/30433) also explains the relationship between AES keys and passwords.